# Invalid callback() argument error with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection like this (very simplified)...

```
var parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    mobile: String
});

var familySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groupId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, index: true },
    parents: [parentSchema]
});
```

For a given group, I'd like to find all of the parents of families in that group who have a mobile value set (exists), and unset those mobile values.

I've been able to piece this much together by looking at other examples...

```
Family.update(
    { groupId: someGroupId, "parents.mobile": {"$exists":"true"} },
    { $unset : { "parents.$.mobile" : 1 } }, false, true
).then(function() {
    // do other stuff
});
```

Running generates the error:

> Trace: [Error: Invalid callback() argument.]

I've tried several variations, but this one seems the most correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) signature for mongoose models is:

```
Model.update(<{query}>,<{update}>,[<{options}>],[callback])
```

So when using promises, it's just the first two with the optional "third" `options`. The "fourth" would be a `callback` function, and hence the error:

```
Family.update(
    { "groupId": someGroupId, "parents.mobile": {"$exists": true } },
    { "$unset": { "parents.$.mobile" : "" } },
    { "multi": true }
).then(function() {
```

Too many people read the ["shell" signature](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), even though the usage of:

```
.update(<{query}>,<{update}>,<upsert>,<multi>)
```

Has been deprecated in favour of the standard "options" arrangement for some time.

Always refer to the method that actually applies to your language API.

Comment: very helpful.  thanks.  i sure wish there was a better way to navigate their api docs than text search on that giant page.   am I missing something there?

Comment: @user1272965 Well the hyperlink I gave you goes straight to the method, so you appear to be missing that and the sidebar on the left with every class ( ie [model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model-js) ) and then each listed method there as well. It's all there if you look.